# Using new Option and styling with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I style the options using JS? Suppose I have this:

```
var optionElementReference = new Option([text, [value, [defaultSelected, [selected]]]]);
```

I want each option to have it's own background color. First option red, second one orange, third one yellow etc. How can I do that?

Comment: Styling `option` elements is very unreliable as some browsers allow some styling rules to be set on those elements, while others disallow them all. If you want to do this you would be better off using a 3rd party plugin to style the entire `select`, such as Select2.

Comment: Would be better to style them in the CSS instead of the JS, via a `.class` on the `select` and leveraging `option:nth-child()` to pick which one you want. Otherwise, Nikki below basically demo'd one way to do it entirely in JS- you set the style on the `option` elements the same way you set the style on any other element.

Comment: hmm thanks, good to know

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how cross browser this is, but it worked in Chrome testing with a Fiddle.

```
document.getElementById("s1").options[0] = new Option("x",0);
document.getElementById("s1").options[1] = new Option("y",1);
var z = new Option("z",2);
z.setAttribute("style","background-color:red");
document.getElementById("s1").options[2] = z;
```